# What is resistance of this SMD trimmer?

Tags: resistors

There is a trimmer on a board that looks like this one
https://www.electronicscomp.com/100k-ohm-smd-single-turn-potentiometer-trimmer-variable-resistance.

But is marked as "2" and "3". This marking is unknown to me. I would suggest value is 2k but if "2"2" is 100k, then its probably wrong

Comment: you can be pretty sure that an arbitrary webshop doesn't take a separate photo for each of the trimmers they sell. That's just a generic photo that doesn't say anything about the actual resistance of that trimmer. In this case, this would have been super easy to find out: all the other SMD trimmers have exactly the same photo in that shop…

Comment: And markings on surface-mount parts can be pretty cryptic.  This is partially because there's just not room for a full description, and partially because doing so makes it harder to reverse-engineer boards.  I build only prototypes, and for me, in the lab, cryptic markings are a bug.  However, when my prototypes go into production, cryptic markings are a feature.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It is much more likely that this is a standard "wiper" element that is used on the full range of pots. It *might* signify that this is connected to pin 2 of the package (which could be confirmed if the shop had posted a datasheet link) but I'd say that this is unlikely as the pinout is so obvious.